# Where exactly to set NOCOUNT ON in stored procedure?

Tags: asp.net, sql, t-sql

I like using stored procedures in ASP.NET and want to make sure I have the exact correct syntax. Are there any significant differences between these?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.mySP
    @param1
AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT f1 FROM foo WHERE f2 = @param1
    END
RETURN
```

What if we don`t use begin, end, or return? Any difference performance-wise?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.mySP
    @param1
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT f1 FROM foo WHERE f2 = @param1
```

Does it make a difference if NOCOUNT is set on before or after BEGIN?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.mySP
    @param1
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    BEGIN
    SELECT f1 FROM foo WHERE f2 = @param1
    END
```

And do we really need return? Visual studio includes it but everything seems to work fine without it. Finally, I have seen it suggested to set NOCOUNT off before returning results but I am not sure why. Thanks!

Comment: Lose the begin and end. They just make your entire SP have to be indented one more level.

Comment: Just wanted to thank everyone for all the helpful answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the things you have mentioned will affect performance, and in reality it is personal preference, but here are my thoughts:

No you don't need `RETURN` unless you want to change the return value from the default of 0. This can be useful for [returning error codes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190778%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) from a procedure.

It doesn't really matter whether or not you include `BEGIN/END`, however I would advise you do, the main reason is just to safeguard against errors, for example if I want to create a procedure to select IDs from 2 tables, foo and bar, and run the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Test
AS
    SELECT ID
    FROM Foo;
    GO
    SELECT ID
    FROM Bar;
GO
```

The procedure will be created, and I'll get the IDs from Bar, and the procedure will be left just returning the IDs from Foo. If I had enclosed the procedure in `BEGIN/END` then it would not have compiled:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Test
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ID
    FROM Foo;
    GO
    SELECT ID
    FROM Bar;
END
GO
```

You can't protect yourself from all errors and typos, and we all make them from time to time, but every little helps!

Finally it doesn't matter whether you put `SET NOCOUNT` before or after the `BEGIN`, but in keeping with the practice of wrapping the whole procedure with `BEGIN/END` then I think it should go after the `BEGIN`.

A lot of this is sourced from [this article](https://sqlblog.org/2008/10/30/my-stored-procedure-best-practices-checklist) by [Aaron Bertrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand), and summarised for this specific question. I am a pretty big fan of all his best practice guides, and that one is no exception.

Comment: I just have to disagree on the BEGIN and END. It is more valuable to me to not have all my code indented an additional block than it is to guard against a potentially stray `GO`. I have never once, in 10 years of SQL Server work, accidentally cut off an SP through the use of a stray `GO`. But I have suffered through far too many indentations.

Comment: @ErikE As I said it is basically just personal preference, and while I cannot recall a situation where a stray `GO` has caused me problems, I also can't recall a situation where indentation has caused me problems either (since Query Analyser for SQL Server 2000 when the indentation from the previous line was not remembered and you had to press tab each time). Given the fact that indentation is optional, i.e. you could just keep the remainder of the query at the same indentation as the first `BEGIN`, and this will never give unexpected behaviour it seems like the lesser of two "evils".

Comment: I guess I just like to avoid putting in unnecessary code. :)

Answer (score 0):

I always include `SET NOCOUNT ON` on the very first line after `BEGIN` statement.

If you are reading SP with application and `SET NOCOUNT OFF` is set on SP. You will get results plus message back. And if you not handling return of that additional message you could run into problems.

That is why it is best to `SET NOCOUNT ON` this way you don't get extra messages that are not really important.

Message Shown:

```
ALTER PROC test
AS
BEGIN   
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.tables
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
END
```

Message Not Shown:

```
ALTER PROC test
AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.tables     
END
```

Comment: That`s actually where I normally include it too but I`m not really sure why. So are you saying putting SET NO COUNT ON right before the begin statement as opposed to after it will cause an additional message?

Comment: no I'm saying that putting `SET NOCOUNT OFF` instead of `SET NOCOUNT ON` will produce extra messages. `SET NOCOUNT ON` can go any time after `AS` but before your return.

Comment: Ok gotcha. I just read somewhere that you 'should' do that (even though I never do)

Comment: I made an addition to answer to show you what happens when `SET NOCOUNT ON` is set after return statement.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need RETURN.

With NOCOUNT set OFF (which is the default - for me anyway), you get a result set for every statement (which may also be closed just to confuse your more). That includes INSERTs and UPDATES and is almost certainly is not what you want. Some providers (ADO with a server cursor) will only handle one record and will throw an exception if there are more than one - usually with a really ugly error message. You only need SET NOCOUNT ON if there are more than one statement -- which in your case there isn't.

I have heard it said that SET NOCOUNT OFF is good practice but it probably doesn't matter.

your BEGIN and ENDs make no difference in this case.

Comment: That`s what I heard too. Do you know why? I don`t do it personally (my stored procs are all pretty basic and I`m the only one doing any development on this DB anyway)

Comment: I think it is just considered good practice. If you turn off a flag on a connection you should turn it back on again (or vice versa). If the connection you are using is pooled maybe the flag persists and could affect other calls. For example the Execute call that returns the number of records affected *may* need NOCOUNT OFF.